# Does anyone know how can i modify alert box with css, or how can i made my own

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Just don't suggest me jquery ui modal because i don't know how to
modify and implement that thing! Alert box work perfect but it's little
ugly, i want to style it and i know that is not maybe possible because
it's system tool..i need help..that modal box need to be opened when
form was submitted, she need to contain message like "your message has
been sent!"..Thank you brothers

Code:

```
echo '
              <!-- Poruka o NEuspiješnosti slanja -->
              <script type="text/javascript">

              alert("Greška!\nMolimo Vas ispravno popunite obrazac.");

              </script>
              <!-- Kraj -->'; } // Kraj.
```

Comment: you cannot re-style native alert box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

somthing like this should work

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
      $('#form').submit(function(e)
       {
           e.preventDefault();
            modal();
        });
    $('.close').click(function()
      {
                          $('#alertBox').fadeOut()
       });
 });
function modal()
{
    $('#alertBox').fadeIn();
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="alertBox">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="msg">your message has been sent!</div>
        <div class="close">close</div>
    </div>
</div>
<form id="form" method="post" action="">
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

CSS

```
#alertBox{
    position:fixed;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    width:400px;
    height:200px;
    margin-left:-200px;
    margin-top:-200px;
    border:2px solid #ccc;
    background:#fafafa;
    display:none;
    font-size:18px;
    text-align:center;

}
.close{
 position:absolute;
 top:5px;
    right:5px;
    cursor:pointer
}
.inner{
    position:relative;
        padding-top:50px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9BrUN/1/

in your case Echo

```
echo'
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){modal()}});
<script>';
```

Comment: there is a demo link tht works
 keep in mide that you should add jquery plugin in your script and add html code written above in your script and of course modal function

Comment: can you modify it for me bro im a noob, i need this window to open when message is sent?? you have code above.

Comment: just add css code written above to your css file and add <script src="http//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script> to your header if you didnt add jquery already and add function modal(){... on your js file and add <div id="alertBox">
    <div class="inner">
        <div class="msg">your message has been sent!</div>
        <div class="close">close</div>
    </div>
</div> somewhere to your html file then replace your PHP echo with echo written above.I hope, answer is clear and you can make it

Comment: thank you bro, your a good man, god bless you and your family.

Comment: bro how can i print this modal in php echo function, i dont need any triger like '("#form").submit', just print it in echo??

Answer (score 2):

You can use [HTML Dialog element (www.w3.org)](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/interactive-elements.html#the-dialog-element), [HTML Dialog element (html5rocks)](http://updates.html5rocks.com/2013/09/dialog-element-Modals-made-easy). You can style it with css, although it's not so widely supported now

Answer (score 0):

Simple Answer. No, You can't

Because `Alertbox` is system object, You cannot modify it with CSS or javascript.

The only way to do is, Use **[Jquery UI Dialog](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/)** as you mentioned in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the alert box.
Instead of alert, use something like:

jQuery:

```
  $('body').append('<div class="error"><span class="error_close">×</span>Greška!<br>Molimo Vas ispravno popunite obrazac.</div>');
$('.error_close').click(function(){$(this).parent().hide();});
```

CSS:

```
.error { position: fixed; z-index: 10000; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; margin: auto; width: 400px; height: 100px; } 
.error_close { position: absolute; top: 5px; right: 5px; }
```